# Function over tidyverse code results in issue with quotes

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

Example of the problem I'm having with applying a function including tidyverse code.  I want to repeat for different variable names, but I'm not sure how to 'unquote'.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(grp=c(1,2,1,2,1), one=c(rep('a', 3), rep('b', 2)), two=c(rep('a', 1), rep('d', 4)))
cn <- colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)]

for(i in cn){
  i <- enquo(i)
  print(df %>% group_by(grp) %>% count(!!i))
}
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp `"one"`     n
  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1     1 one         3
2     2 one         2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp `"two"`     n
  <dbl> <chr>   <int>
1     1 two         3
2     2 two         2
```

Doing it for a single variable named one; this is the correct output.

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% count(one)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   grp [2]
    grp one       n
  <dbl> <fct> <int>
1     1 a         2
2     1 b         1
3     2 a         1
4     2 b         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map`, also can avoid `group_by` by including `grp` in `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(cn, ~df %>% count(grp, .data[[.x]]))

#[[1]]
#  grp one n
#1   1   a 2
#2   1   b 1
#3   2   a 1
#4   2   b 1

#[[2]]
#  grp two n
#1   1   a 1
#2   1   d 2
#3   2   d 2
```

You can also use `NSE` with `sym`

```
map(cn, ~df %>% count(grp, !!sym(.x)))
```